# Stop browser from loading after form onsubmit function is done

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript that generates a form with an onsubmit event handler.  The form is defined like this:

```
document.writeln('<form action="#" id="loginForm" onsubmit="processLoginForm(this);">');
```

In this processLoginForm() function I am basically printing a form value and returning:

```
function processLoginForm(form) {
    var userName = form.uname.value;
    document.writeln("username = "+userName+"<br>");
    return false;
};
```

When this form is loaded, the browser loading is complete and done.  Loading the page is done by the browser.  But when I click on the button to submit the form, my code is processed but my browser is still trying to load something that it shows this loading icon and never stops.  I tried returning true, false, or nothing in processLoginForm() function, but it has no impact.

How can I make my browser to stop loading when my submit handler is done?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not putting your function inline into the HTML. Instead do this:

## HTML

```
<form action="#" id="loginForm">
```

## JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('loginForm').onsubmit = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    //continue to process the form
}
```

The `event.preventDefault()` method which is attached to the `event` argument that is automatically passed in event listeners will cancel the default action of the handler. In this case, trying to load a page located at `/#` (according to your form action).

Comment: It sounded good, but unfortunately, this is not working as expected.  I still have the exact same problem.